# Ubuntu won't execute script on shutdown/restart

Tags: bash, shutdown, restart

I've been looking through various pages on this site and others looking for a way to execute a script on shutdown and restart, but none of them are working for me.

I've tried placing bash scripts in `/etc/init.d/` and linking them to `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d/`, but they won't run on shutdown or restart. I've also tried using the `update-rc.d` command to create new services, but

1. they don't work, and
2. they don't even create a new link in the `rc?.d` folders.

Comment: sysvinit used /etc/rc*.d/, but sysvinit was long ago replaced by Upstart, which was in turn replaced years ago by systemd. See [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/) for good advice.

Comment: One big problem with using sysvinit scripts for shutdown/restart is that they are easy to (unintentionally) bypass. That's why most housekeeping (like clearing /tmp) occurs at startup instead.

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate, and for what it's worth I managed to get it working. Thanks for the help.